# Android app update after server change

Tags: android

I'm new on android developping and I want to create an small app whitch parse my php file from my server.

I can parse a php file, but if php file change my apps doesn't update - I must close app and reopen. What is best way to check if php file is updated and show updated file?

Or insert timer in app? But I think this is not best way to insert timer every  1 seconds to check php file and update app screen. Maybe everyone know where find tutorial or something?

Comment: maybe https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ can help

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways

1. use push notification to notify devices that php file is updated.
2. check file whether it is changed or not on regular intervel.

in my opinion 1st way is far better. Because when you use 2nd way, it might consume more battery and internet data usage.

Comment: what way using gmail, facebook and other apps?